# How to determine the length of $x$ in this sketch?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the following construction:
[image: What is x?]
Assume that you are given the lengths of the sides $a,b,c,d,e$ as well as the size of the angle $\phi$. The task is to determine the length of $x$ in terms of the given parameters.

I've found that $x$ has to satisfy the equation
$$\frac{c^2+x^2-d^2}{2cx}=\cos(\phi) \frac{b^2+(x+e)^2-a^2}{2b(x+e)} + \sin(\phi) \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{b^2+(x+e)^2-a^2}{2b(x+e)}\right)^2}.$$

However, I don't see any possibility to solve this equation (which yields something like a polynomial of 6th degree in $x$) explicitly.

Comment: I can't help but seeing this as a 3D drawing.

Comment: However, it is meant to be completely 2D.

Comment: My own attempt also gives a 6th-degree polynomial in $x$. (The condition $c=d$ reduces its degree to $4$, which makes the polynomial solvable explicitly although not prettily.) Do you have a reason for believing there's an explicit answer here?

Comment: LIke Blue I, too, would consider it likely that there is no easier solution. Unless you have any indication to the contrary. I constructed this as an intersection of curves, but one of the curves involved seems to have at least degree 3, and it gets intersected with a circle. Do you have explicit values for these lengths, which might make the situation easier? Or would a numeric approximation be feasible, too?